Script to read the Network tab in Google Chrome's Developer tool
I would like to create a script (which may become a Chrome extension in the future) that reads the request log and searches for keywords in urls. The goal is to build a script that replaces the manual check of the:

open Network
filter for a word/keyword
see what clicks in the request urls.

If it finds something then it creates a popup to alert me otherwise it returns an error.
I have tried several scripts but it seems that the problem is in reading the network log.
This is the last script I used, how can I improve it?


// Funzione per monitorare le richieste di rete
function monitorNetworkRequests() {
  // Intercetta le richieste di rete usando l'API PerformanceObserver
  const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    const entries = list.getEntries();

    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const url = entry.name.toLowerCase();

      // Controlla se l'URL contiene "adform" o "doubleclick"
      if (url.includes("adform")) {
        showPopup("Tracciamenti di adform implementati!");
      } else if (url.includes("doubleclick")) {
        showPopup("Tracciamenti di doubleclick implementati!");
      } else {
        showPopup("Tracciamenti non implementati!");
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe({ type: "resource", buffered: true });
}

// Funzione per mostrare un popup al centro dello schermo
function showPopup(message) {
  const popup = document.createElement("div");
  popup.innerText = message;
  popup.style.position = "fixed";
  popup.style.top = "50%";
  popup.style.left = "50%";
  popup.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  popup.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
  popup.style.color = "white";
  popup.style.padding = "20px";
  popup.style.borderRadius = "8px";
  popup.style.fontSize = "16px";
  popup.style.zIndex = "10000";

  document.body.appendChild(popup);

  // Rimuove il popup dopo 3 secondi
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.remove();
  }, 3000);
}

// Avvia il monitoraggio delle richieste di rete
monitorNetworkRequests();




What is "keywork"?  (a typo?  Did you mean "keyword"?)

"it returns an error. " What's the error? What exactly is the problem when reading the network log?

yes it was typo Wyck, edited :)
@mykaf I mean: if the keyword was found in the urls we'll say an ok in the popup, otherwise it will say "no keyword found, error"

but "the problem is in reading the network log"; what is the problem here? Does it not do it at all? Does it do it wrong?
